# Sometime networkonmainthreadexception in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I am getting NetworkonMainThreadException sometime.I dont know what is the problem. First time it opens with no error, But after few times closing and opening cause the NetworkOnMainThreadException.

> Below is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
    new DownloadWebpageTask().execute();
}  

@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);  
    return true;  
}  

private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    List<Member> members = new ArrayList<Member>();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String ss = "";
    InputStream is;
    HttpURLConnection connection ;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.107:8080/SEWS_webservice/rest/members");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            is = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e+"***********************&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
        }finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

        return ss;
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        XmlPullParserHandler parser = new XmlPullParserHandler();           
        parser.parse(is);
        members = parser.getMembers();
        ArrayAdapter<Member> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Member>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, members);  
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

}

> This is XMLPullParser handler

```
public class XmlPullParserHandler {  
    private List<Member> members= new ArrayList<Member>();  
    private Member member;  
    private String text;  

    public List<Member> getMembers() {  
        return members;  
    }  

    public List<Member> parse(InputStream is) {

           try {  
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();  
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);  
            XmlPullParser  parser = factory.newPullParser();  

            parser.setInput(is, null);  

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();  

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {  
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {  
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:  
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("member")) {  
                        // create a new instance of employee
                        member = new Member();  
                    }  
                    break;  

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:  
                    text = parser.getText();  
                    break;  

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:  
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("member")) {  
                        // add employee object to list  
                        members.add(member);  
                    }else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("memberId")) {
                        member.setMemberId(Integer.parseInt(text));  
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("firstName")) {
                        member.setFirstName(text);  
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("middleName")) {
                        member.setMiddleName(text);  
                    }                        
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("lastName")) {
                        member.setLastName(text);  
                    }                        

                    break;  
                default:  
                    break;  
                }  
                eventType = parser.next();  
            }  

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
        return members;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: please add the stack trace with the exception

Comment: Dude, please choose answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is even though you are connecting up to the website properly in the background you are reading from the underlying socket using the InputStream. You need to refactor your solution so that you are returning a String or raw data from your InputStream as the result of doInBackground and closing out any http connections. Something like

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

```
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.107:8080/SEWS_webservice/rest/members");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        is = connection.getInputStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream oStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int numRead = -1;
        while ((numRead = (is.read(buffer))) > -1) {
           oStream.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
        return new String(oStream.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e+"***********************&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
    }finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }

    return ss;
}

// onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    XmlPullParserHandler parser = new XmlPullParserHandler();           
    parser.parse(result);
    members = parser.getMembers();
    ArrayAdapter<Member> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Member>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, members);  
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Should do it if the XmlPullParserHandler can read Strings, otherwise that too will need to get moved to the background portion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `XmlPullParser` doesn't like to work on UI thread :)
I could not find exact proves of this, but even [official example](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#consume) makes it work in `AsyncTask`.

In your case just try to move next lines:

```
XmlPullParserHandler parser = new XmlPullParserHandler();           
parser.parse(is);
members = parser.getMembers();
```

into `doInBackground()` method and check the result.

**PS.** Not relating to question, but what is purpose of this `String ss = "";`?
You can change `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` to `AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>` if you don't want to return anything.
Or, better way, - you can do this `AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Member>>`.
Then you make `protected void onPostExecute(List<Member> result)` and use this `result` in your `Adapter` code.

Comment: Glad to here that. If so, please mark an answer as correct. If you wish, you can also upvote it. Thanks.